# Editing a regex that isn't mine, not sure how to adjust it for needs

Tags: php, regex, string-length

I have a regex that was written for me for passwords:

```
~^[a-z0-9!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)]{8,16}$~i
```

It's supposed to match strings of alphanumerics and symbols of 8-16 characters.  Now I need to remove the min and max length requirement as I need to split the error messages for user friendliness - I tried to just take out the {8,16} portion but then it breaks it.  How would I do this?  Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you're doing separate checks for too-long or too-short strings, and this regex is only making sure there are no invalid characters.  This should do it:

```
~^[a-z0-9!@#$%^&*()]+$~i
```

`+` means *one or more*, `*` means *zero or more*; it probably doesn't matter which one you use.

I got rid of some unnecessary backslashes, too; none of those characters has any special meaning in a character class (inside the square brackets, that is).